# Dynamically write mysql table schema into Avro format

Tags: python, mysql, avro

I want to collect the data from Mysql table and converet it to avro format using python.

**Consider this table in mysql**

```
dept_no, dept_name
'd001', 'Marketing'
'd002', 'Finance'
'd003', 'Human Resources'
'd004', 'Production'
'd005', 'Development'
'd006', 'Quality Management'
'd007', 'Sales'
'd008', 'Research'
'd009', 'Customer Service'
```

mycursor.execute('select * from employees')
results = mycursor.fetchall()

when i fetch the results using above query 
i get the results in a class-tuple format.

Where as to convert to Avro format, Schema as to be defined in the following format:
By hard-coding we can achieve the below format

**The Following code is to generate avro file.**

```
schema = {
    'doc': 'A weather reading.',
    'name': 'Weather',
    'namespace': 'test',
    'type': 'record',
    'fields': [

        {'name': 'dept_no', 'type': 'string'},
        {'name': 'dept_name', 'type': 'string'},


    ],
}


And the  records as 
records = [

    {u'dept_no': u'd001', u'dept_name': 'Marketing'}, 
    {u'dept_no': u'd002', u'dept_name': 'Finance'}, 
    {u'dept_no': u'd003', u'dept_name': 'Human Resources'},
    {u'dept_no': u'd004', u'dept_name': 'Production'}, 

]
```

The Question Here is How do i MAP the schema and the data in the above format using Python dynamically.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="********************",
    user="***********",
    passwd="**********",
    database='***********'
)


def byte_to_string(x):
    temp_table_list = []
    for row in x:
        table = row[0].decode()
        temp_table_list.append(table)
    return temp_table_list


mycursor = mydb.cursor()
#Query to list all the tables
mycursor.execute("show tables")
r = mycursor.fetchall()
r = byte_to_string(r)
print(r)
x = len(r)

#Fetch all the records from table EMPLOYEES using Select *
mycursor.execute('select * from employees')
results = mycursor.fetchall()
print(type(results))
print(results)
#Displays Data of table employee record by record
for i in results:
    print(i)
    print(type(i))


#Fectching data from 2nd table departments
mycursor.execute('select * from departments')
data=[i[0] for i in mycursor.fetchall()]
mycursor.execute('select * from departments')
data1=[i[1] for i in mycursor.fetchall()]
print(data)
print(data1)
#zipbObj = zip(data,data1)

#dictOfWords = dict(zipbObj)
#print(dictOfWords)

mycursor.execute('SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`\
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`\
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`="triggerdb1"\
    AND `TABLE_NAME`="departments"')
#Fetching the column names of the table as keys
keys=[i[0] for i in mycursor.fetchall()]
print(keys)
'''
zipbObj = zip(column_schema,data1)
dictOfWords = dict(zipbObj)
print(dictOfWords)
'''

#Finally we get the Header as key and records as values in a dict format

abc = {}
abc[keys[0]] = data1
abc[keys[1]] = data
print(abc)



The result is in the form of 

#print(data)
>>>'d001', 'd002', 'd003', 'd004', 'd005', 'd006', 'd007', 'd008', 'd009']

#print(data1)
>>>['Marketing', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Production', 'Development', 'Quality Management', 'Sales', 'Research', 'Customer Service']


#print(keys)
>>>['dept_no', 'dept_name']


#print(abc)
>>>{'dept_no': ['Marketing', 'Finance', 'Human Resources', 'Production', 'Development', 'Quality Management', 'Sales', 'Research', 'Customer Service'], 'dept_name': ['d001', 'd002', 'd003', 'd004', 'd005', 'd006', 'd007', 'd008', 'd009']}
```

**The Question Here is How do i dynamically MAP the schema and the data from the resulting class Tuple/Dictionary and covert to avro using Python.**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You seem to have a broad question like, "how do I make a website". Consider taking a stab at it first and then asking a more specific question.

Comment: Yeah Thats True in a way. Thank you @Eric Fossum i will try to put it in a better way. Any thoughts so far?